# Convert array to associative array with specific key and value

Tags: php

I need to convert an array into associative array as first element should act as a key and second element should act as its value ?please tell me how i can do that

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work? What is your code? How does your array look? We can't guess these things. It'd be like asking "*my car doesn't work - please tell me what is wrong*".

Comment: Really? What's unclear? He want to convert array like [1, 2, 3, 4] to [1 => 2, 3 => 4]... Simple...

Comment: He wrote "first element should act as a key and second element should act as its value", so array contains only two values - first and second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only two elements (first and second as you mentioned), then you can do simply like this

`$assoc = array($simple[0] => $simple[1]);`

If you wanted to convert pairs of values like [1,2,3,4] to [1=>2,3=>4], then use this code snippet

```
$assoc = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($simple); $i=$i+2) {
    $assoc[$simple[$i]] = $simple[$i+1];
}
```

Comment: edited my answer above